# Adding an auto increment sql script

Tags: mysql, concatenation, auto-increment, post-increment

I have a child table named `case_parties`, that consists of the name and address of each plaintiff and defendant to court cases.

The table columns include:

- `case_id`, which is a foreign key to the parent table
- `party_type`, which has coded field values of either 1 or 2 (1 indicating a plaintiff and 2 indicating a defendant).  The caveat is that there is not always just 1 plaintiff and 1 defendant in every court case.  Often, there are multiple plaintiffs and or multiple defendants in a single case. There can be anywhere from 1 to 1,000 + plaintiffs and or defendants on any given case.  I created a new column, lets call it `party_id` and `SET` it with a `CONCAT` on the `case_id` and `party_type` columns.  Therefore, matching rows in this column include either all the plaintiffs or all the defendants to a given `case_id`.

To create a simple unique key for each row, I want to run a script that adds an auto generated incremental number or letter to the end of the matching `party_id` field.  For example, if there are 4 plaintiffs in the same court case, there are now 4 columns with matching `party_id` field values, with the last character being 1, representing the party is a plaintiff;

I want to add an increment on so each column is unique and the last two digits of the 4 rows would reflect something like this: "1A", "1B", "1C", "1D" or "1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "1-4",...etc.  I'm thinking adding incremental numbers might be easier than adding incremental letters.  No other column values individually or collectively make for an efficient composite index in this case.  I'm seeking assistance with auto incrementing the matching column values and would greatly appreciate any assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it would make much of a difference solution wise, but the "party_id" column filed type is VARCHAR and the resulting or edited column which will uniquely identify each individual party must also be VARCHAR.

Comment: why must it be a VARCHAR? ideally you want to let the database handle the uniqueness for you with a primary key.

Comment: Because a large number of the case id #'s contains letters and the id number is rather long.  I know long primary keys are not recommended by I have no choice in this situation.  Also, this is just a production database that is going to be used to extract raw data that will be turned into more manicured datasets.  So Im not so worried about performance in this production DB.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a separate table to represent the defendant/plaintiffs and have a type column in there. Then have a primary key on that table with a regular auto-increment.

You can then use that as your ID in the `case_parties` table (a foreign key) and it will address your issue with uniquely identifying each one.

Comment: They're already in a "case_parties" table, which includes the party type.  I don't think you understand my question entirely, please read it again.

Comment: Unless you mean separate the table into two tables "plaintiffs" and defendants", then order then and set an auto increment..yeah..dont wanna do that.

Comment: and that wouldn't work anyway.  The auto increment count must restart at the first party type for each case.

Comment: What about adding an additional column and setting that column to populate as the occurrence number of the matching party type?  There must be a simple script that can populate a column reflecting the numeric instance for each row w a matching "party_id".  Anybody?